# Why is bitwise operator needed in this powerset generator?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am currently following MITx's 6.00.2x, and we are asked to come up with a variant of power set generator of the one at the bottom.

But before I can work on the variant, I do not even understand what's going on with the given generator. Specifically:

1. What does `(i >> j) % 2 == 1`, and in fact the whole `for j in range(N):` block do? I understand that `i >> j` shifts
   the binary of `i` by `j`, then returns the decimal representation of
   that shifted binary number. But I have absolutely no clue why binary
   is even needed in a powerset generator in the first place, let alone
   the necessity of this conditional.
2. I understand that for any given set A a cardinality n, the
   cardinality of its powerset is 2**n - because for every subset of A
   every member is either in or not, and we repeat that for n times.

   Is that what `for i in range(2**N):` is doing? i.e. going over 2**n subsets and either include or not include any given member of the set?

I tried running it with `items=['apple,'banana','orange']` and `items=[1,2,3]`, and both returned an empty list, which makes it all the more confusing.

```
def powerSet(items):
    # generate all combinations of N items, items is a Python list
    N = len(items)
    # enumerate the 2**N possible combinations
    for i in range(2**N):
        combo = []
        for j in range(N):
            # test bit jth of integer i
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                combo.append(items[j])
        return combo
```

Comment: There's actually a comment directly above it. That's what it does. Imagine the integer i in a binary representation. The shift drops all the positions to the right of the one you want. The %2 drops all the ones to the left of the one you want. Leaving you with exactly 1 binary digit, which you check == 1

Comment: @KennyOstrom The comment does not at all help me to understand the logic of it I am afraid...

Comment: My guess is it returns an empty list because the final `return` is at the wrong indentation.

Comment: Your question is somewhat contradictory, because point 2 basically explains the question at 1. Each number from to 0 to 2**N represents one possible subset, and the j-th bit in this number tells if the j-th element is included in this subset (=1) or not (=0).

Comment: Perhaps a starting point would be helpful. Do you understand binary numbers? Modulo arithmetic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the algorithm here starts with an observation that any subset of `{1,...,N}` can be seen as a function `f:{1,...,N}->{0,1}`, i.e. the characteristic function. How it works? Well, if `A` is a subset of `{1,...,N}` then `f` is given by `f(x)=0` if `x` not in `A` and `f(x)=1` otherwise.

Now another observation is that any function `f:{1,...,N}->{0,1}` can be encoded as a binary number of `N` bits: j-th bit is 1 if `f(j)=1` and 0 otherwise.

And so if we want to generate all subsets of `{1,..,N}` it is enough to generate all binary numbers of length `N`. So how many such numbers are there? Of course `2**N`. And since every number between `0` and `2**N - 1` (`-1` since we count from `0`) uniquely corresponds to some subset of `{1,...,N}` then we can simply loop through them. That's where the `for i in range(2**N):` loop comes from.

But we don't simply deal with subsets of `{1,...,N}`, we actually have some unknown set/list `items` of length `N`. So if `A` is a subset of `{1,...,N}`, meaning `A` is a number between `0` and `2**N - 1` then how do we convert it to a subset of `items`? Well, again, we use the fact that the bit `1` corresponds to "is in set" and the bit `0` corresponds to "is not in set". And that's where `(i >> j) % 2 == 1` comes from. It simply means "if j-th bit is 1" which in the consequence leads to "j-th element should be in the subset".

There's a slight issue with your code. You should maybe yield instead of return:

```
def powerSet(items):
    N = len(items)
    for i in range(2**N):
        combo = []  # <-- this is our subset
        for j in range(N):
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                combo.append(items[j])
        yield combo  # <-- here we yield it to caller

subsets = list(powerSet(["apple", "banana", "pear"]))
```

---

Here's an example of this binary encoding of subsets. Say you have a list

> ["apple", "banana", "pear"]

It has 3 elements so we are looking at numbers of (binary) length 3. So here are all possible subsets and their encodings in the "loop" order:

> 000 == []
>
> 001 == ["apple"]
>
> 010 == ["banana"]
>
> 011 == ["apple", "banana"]
>
> 100 == ["pear"]
>
> 101 == ["apple", "pear"]
>
> 110 == ["banana", "pear"]
>
> 111 == ["apple", "banana", "pear"]

Answer (score 3):

Your code was basically creating new lists in every loop and not saving the previous results.

Here is the corrected code to get all combinations:

```
def powerSet(items):
    # generate all combinations of N items, items is a Python list
    N = len(items)

    # This will store the complete set of combinations     
    outer_combo = []

    # enumerate the 2**N possible combinations
    for i in range(2**N):

        # This will store the intermediate sets 
        inner_combo = []
        for j in range(N):
            # test bit jth of integer i
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                inner_combo.append(items[j])

        # Uncomment below to understand each step
        # print(inner_combo)

        # Add the intermediate set to final result
        outer_combo.append(inner_combo)
    return outer_combo

print(powerSet([1,2,3]))
# Output : [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Now lets come to your points:

- Basically you are generating all numbers from 0 to `(2**N)-1`. So, in our example `[1, 2, 3]`, `i` has the values `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`
- The binary representation of these values is 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111 respectively
- Using `i>>j` you are basically trying to shift all the `1`'s in each binary representation to the right most side.
- Then using `(i>>j)%2==1` you are checking if 1 even exists at all
- The second loop `for j in range(N):` will help using in two ways. First here `N` not only stores the number of elements in list, but all the number of relevant bits to look up in the operation `(i>>j)%2==1`. This is because, internally the binary representation can have upto 64 bits, but the relevant bits here are the first N bits (remember the operation (2**N)-1 ?). Secondly, this will shift the bits N times to right to check how many `1's` are actually there.
- An example is something like this. For example, `i=5` i.e. `101`. Now `j` can have values `0, 1, 2`. So, in first case when `j=0`, the operation `(i>>j)%2==1` will return True since the bit at 0th position is 1. So, `item[0]`, i.e. `1` is appended to intermediate combination, i.e. we have `[1]` till now. Now `j=1` and the operation `(i>>j)%2==1` will return False since the bit at 1st position is 0. So no element is added. Finally, when `j=2`, `(i>>j)%2==1` will return True since the bit at 2nd position is 1. Hence `item[2]`, i.e. 3 is added to the intermediate result, i.e. the set now becomes `[1, 3]`.